# Creating and running cron job on symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I have created cron job on symfony with `.symfony.cloud.yaml`located in root directory of project. My `app:check-new-users` command is working properly when I run `symfony bin/console app:check-new-users`.

**.symfony.cloud.yaml**

```
timezone: Europe/Istanbul
crons:
    testt:
        spec: '1 * * * *'
        cmd: |
            if [ "$SYMFONY_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then
                croncape symfony console app:check-new-users
            fi
```

But when I run `symfony cron testtt` it's giving an error like this: **Hello user, you successfully authenticated, but could not connect to service hh648494984984rahvnyu-drxfzjbq2a--app (reason: service doesn't exist or you do not have access to it)**

I want to run this cron job automatically when I start the server and it must be run every minutes. How can I do this?